# Error message even though obligatory field is filled in

Tags: html

I apologise beforehand since I am very new to this and there might be a very obvious mistake in my code.
I am making a survey and I need the participants to fill in the age field. I have the questions on the demographic data coded as a table and I had the code from somewhere else, am just adapting it.  I wanted the survey to look better and found a way to push the obligatory text field below the age question rather than next to it. Ever since I did that I get an error message. Sometimes it says "Bad value for ‘age’", sometimes it says "The ‘age’ field is obligatory." even though the age field is filled in.

This is how the bit of the (apparently erroneous) code looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td><b>1. How old are you?</b><br><input name="age" type="text" size="3"   class="obligatory" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><label class="error" for="age"></label></td>
</tr>
```

This is what it what it looked like when it still worked:

```
<tr>
  <td>Age:</td><td><input name="age" type="text" size="2" class="obligatory" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><label class="error" for="age"></label></td>
</tr>
```

Could anyone point out to me which bit in the code exactly it is that is causing this error?

Comment: Check for `required`. The form won't submit if the fild with `required` isn't filled BUT work for IE 10>, Opera 9.6> and doesn't work with Safary

Answer (score 0):

> I am making a survey and **I need the participants to fill in the age
>   field.**

---

Add `required` attribute to your input field, like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Age:</td>
  <td><input name="age" type="text" size="2" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><label class="error" for="age"></label></td>
</tr>
```

It would definitely do the job, because form can't be send it required input field isn't filled. Even if you try to hit the submit button before filling required field, browser will raise an alert for your information.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Unfortunately it didn't change anything. You copied the second code I posted and changed the class="obligatory" for required. This code worked anyway. The first code I posted is the one that doesnt work, but I need it to work because the form looks much better this way. 
The problem is not that the field is not required. It is pretty much the opposite. I fill in the field and it will tell me I need to fill in the field and wont let me procede. Even though the field IS actually filled in.
Any other suggestions anyone?

Comment: Umm.. if you use required attribute you won't have a problem when you fill a field and you cannot procede. It only allows to send the form when there is something in your field. Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: I did this:
    <tr>
      <td><b>1. How old are you?</b><br><input name="age" type="text" size="3"   required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label class="error" for="age"></label></td>
    </tr>
Unfortunately I still had the same problem. ;/

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the rest of my code (that I didn't post here) and it worked! So the error must be somewhere else in the code. Sorry everyone.